# 2 UITableView in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with 2 pages in my app and each page has a `UITableView` with some rows in it. The problem is that the touches are really weird. If I want to go to the second page while i am on the first one, i would simply swipe to the left from the right to go to the other page but the `UITableView` detects the swipe as a vertical swipe and "takes" the touch. I have to try 3-4 times to be successfully able to go to the other page. This is very annoying and I was wondering if somebody had a way to make the touches better.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to lock the scrollview:

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can keep customezed scroller bar for scroll view ... so user will scroll from that scroller...... and ofcource if u r inserting table view in scroll view then there are two delegates one of scroller and other of table now how u will control both...i thnk its not good ...so make any one of them customize so u will get its controll how you want.. and its best always that we keep customize scroll bar bcoz its very outer part of coding....

Answer (score 1):

try setting directionalLockEnabled property of scrollBar.

> self.scrollBar.directionalLockEnabled = YES;

Comment: I don't have the scrollbar enabled. The UIScrollView is horizontal and the tableviews are vertical (Obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Keep the frame.height of scroll bar equal to tableview.frame.height.

Set the directional lock property for tableView.

```
self.tableView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you move page just make `(UITableView)tblView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`,
so it call the touch event of `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to make scrolling properly

```
scrollViewContainer.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

More way to lock the scrollview.

1)

```
scrollViewContainer.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

2)

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

3)

```
self.scrollBar.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Like this.......I hope this is helpful for you.